# How to print excel file from java?

Tags: java, printing

First Question on the community!

Let me explain a little the question.

I have a user interface, that allows me to create an excel file. And I want to add at that ui the a "print Document" button. This button is supposed to allow the user to print that excel document. So what I need is a way to call the windows printing dialog for that file, so the user can print the file.

I have read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html, But I can not find the way of telling the printing dialog what file to print.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think what you are asking is an OS-specific thing.  You want your app to trigger Excel to open the file and print it.  So you must ask yourself: Is there a way in Windows to print an Excel doc from command line?  The other alternative is to load the Excel file within your application, then print it from there.  There are a few APIs, I think POI is one and JExcelAPI is another.

Comment: Thanks for your imput. The idea will be opening the print Dialog, without opening the file. As You suggested, printing from command line will be a good option. Unfortunatelly, I am not able to find a printing command for .xls files.

Comment: Even when you print something in Windows from Explorer, it opens the Excel app, does the Print dialog, then closes it.  I think you are stuck either printing yourself via some library that can read Excel, can find a way to call it via CLI, or maybe use JNI to call some native Windows APIs to do it.

Comment: I guess there is no way to print the document, whithout openning IT. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: What it comes down to is that the Print Dialog doesn't actually print anything, it's a dialog to configure where the print will go and how.  The application is still responsible for making whatever calls are necessary to do the actual "printing".  It works that way no matter what language you are in.  Java adds some additional complications in that they have to do things in a very platform-neutral way.  You best bet is to look at library to allow you to open the Excel file and print it.  @Nik below posted some code on how to read in a file, you would just have to send it to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apache POI is the best thing for you. Code syntax is like

```
      POIFSFileSystem filesystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
        HSSFWorkbook wrkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(filesystem );
        HSSFSheet sheet = wrkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;
//Keep on doing your manipulation.
```

More about [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).

Comment: I used this library to create the document that needs to be printed. But It does not allow to print document, as far as I know.

Comment: Okay do you need to print it in CL?